# Sequelize Select column WHERE other column has not contain value

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following `Accounts_Users table`:

```
account_id | user_id
--------------------
1          | 60
2          | 60
1          | 50
3          | 50
```

And I want to retrieve all the user_id's which do not have rows with certain account_id
For example, if the account_id = 2 I want the result should be:

```
user_id
-------
50
```

Since user_id = 60 have record with account = 2.

my current query looks like this:

```
let existingUserIdsWithAccountUser = await AccountUserModel.findAll({
    raw: true,
    where: {
      account_id: account_id,
      user_id: {
        [Sequelize.Op.in]: existingUsersIds
      }
    },
          attributes: [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('user_id')), 'user_id']

  }).map(user => user.user_id);
  const existingUserIdsWithoutAccountUser = existingUsersIds.filter(user_id => !existingUserIdsWithAccountUser.includes(user_id));
```

I want to do a single query without having to filter the results.

I also tired the following:

```
    let existingUserIdsWithoutAccountUser = await AccountUserModel.findAll({
          raw: true,
          where: {
            account_id: {
              [Sequelize.Op.not]: account_id
            },
            user_id: {
              [Sequelize.Op.in]: existingUsersIds
            }
          },
  attributes: [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('user_id')), 'user_id']
        }).map(user => user.user_id);
```

but in this case, if I have a record with a different account_id then it still gets returned obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to do it using the following query:

```
const existingUserIdsWithoutAccountUser = await AccountUserModel.findAll({
      raw: true,
      where: {
        user_id: {
          [Sequelize.Op.and]: {
            [Sequelize.Op.notIn]: Sequelize.literal(`(SELECT user_id FROM \`Accounts_Users\` WHERE account_id = ${account_id})`),
            [Sequelize.Op.in]: existingUsersIds
          }
        }
      },
      attributes: [Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('user_id')), 'user_id']
    }).map(user => user.user_id);
```

Comment: That's why things like sqlize are crap in the first place. Just write a raw query. Why make a wonky query abstraction on top of a solid query language?

Comment: @TheFool sometimes it is indeed a pain in the ass, but many times the abstraction is useful and saves you a lot of time. Their documentation  however is awful

Comment: If you know SQL well, I don't see how it would save you a lot of time. Especially when you consider the time lost on problems like this.